# Data Masking in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-masking

- I have a dataframe with 8 unique values

  ```
   data<-data.frame(id=c("ab","cc","cc","dd","ee","ff","ee","ff","ab","dd","gg",1,"air"))
   >data
         id
      1  ab
      2  cc
      3  cc
      4  dd
      5  ee
      6  ff
      7  ee
      8  ff
      9  ab
      10 dd
      11 gg
      12 1
      13 air
  ```
- I create another dataframe holding 8 unique values that are to be used as replacements

  ```
   library(random)
   replacements<-data.frame(value=randomStrings(n=8, len=2, digits=FALSE,loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE))
   replacements 
    V1
   1 SJ
   2 fH
   3 TZ
   4 Mr
   5 oZ
   6 kZ
   7 fe
   8 ql
  ```
- I want to replace all unique values from `data dataframe` with values in `replacement dataframe` in below way

All ab values replaced by SJ
All cc values replaced by fH
All dd values replaced by TZ
All ee values replaced by Mr
All ff values replaced by oZ
All gg values replaced by kZ
All 1 values replaced by fe
All air values replaced by ql

- Currently, I am achieving this by:

  ```
      data<-data.frame(id=c("ab","cc","cc","dd","ee","ff","ee","ff","ab","dd","gg",1,"air"))
      data$id<-as.character(data$id)
      replacements<-data.frame(value=randomStrings(n=8, len=2, digits=FALSE,loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE))
      replacements$V1<-as.character(replacements$V1)
      for(i in 1:length(unique(data$id))){
           data$id[data$id %in% data$id[i]] <- replacements$V1[i]
      }  


      >data
         id
      1  SJ
      2  fH
      3  fH
      4  TZ
      5  Mr
      6  oZ
      7  Mr
      8  oZ
      9  SJ
      10 TZ
      11 kZ
      12 fe
      13 ql
  ```
- Is there any base function in R to achieve? Is there **better approach** than this for masking data?

Comment: Try `setNames(replacements$V1, as.character(unique(data$id)))[as.character(data$id)]`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `merge()`, but to do that you would first need to add a column of unique `data$id` to `replacements`, as both data.frames need to have a column in common.

Here's `data`:

```
> data
    id
1   ab
2   cc
3   cc
4   dd
5   ee
6   ff
7   ee
8   ff
9   ab
10  dd
11  gg
12   1
13 air
```

Here's `replacements`:

```
> replacements
  V1
1 VS
2 Of
3 bH
4 iJ
5 jm
6 kH
7 cm
8 rQ
```

So add unique `data$id` to `replacements`:

```
replacements$id <- unique(data$id)
```

Giving:

```
  V1  id
1 VS  ab
2 Of  cc
3 bH  dd
4 iJ  ee
5 jm  ff
6 kH  gg
7 cm   1
8 rQ air
```

Then merge `data` with `replacements` using `id`:

```
data <- merge(data, replacements, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Giving:

```
    id V1
1   ab VS
2   ab VS
3   cc Of
4   cc Of
5   dd bH
6   dd bH
7   ee iJ
8   ee iJ
9   ff jm
10  ff jm
11  gg kH
12   1 cm
13 air rQ
```

If you really wanted to keep only the new `id` column, you could drop the original `id` and rename the new column:

```
data <- data[, 2, drop = FALSE]
colnames(data) <- "id"
```

Giving:

```
   id
1  VS
2  VS
3  Of
4  Of
5  bH
6  bH
7  iJ
8  iJ
9  jm
10 jm
11 kH
12 cm
13 rQ
```

Answer (score 1):

- Masking data using algorithm `CRC32`

  ```
  library(data.table)
  library(digest)
  data<-data.frame(id=c("ab","cc","cc","dd","ee","ff","ee","ff","ab","dd","gg",1,"air"))
  setDT(data)

  anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32"){
      unq_hashes <- vapply(unique(x), function(object) digest(object, algo=algo), FUN.VALUE="", USE.NAMES=TRUE)
      unname(unq_hashes[x])
  }

  cols_to_mask <- c("id")
  data[,cols_to_mask := lapply(.SD, anonymize),.SDcols=cols_to_mask,with=FALSE]
  ```

References:[Data anonymization in R](https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2014-11-07/Data-Anonymization-in-R.html)